# MultiFernet in Python assigning created list

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I've been playing with the Fernet module in cryptography.fernet for Python 3.7 to try and create a rotating key structure, and recently discovered MultiFernet; where you provide a *list* to MultiFernet and are able to encode with index 0, and decode from a list of trial-and-error values within the MultiFernet list. (I hope that makes sense).

However, there seems to be a discrepancy between the way the module behaves and the documentation provided by [this document, pages 9 and 10](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cryptography/latest/cryptography.pdf).  Essentially, if I have a pre-created list of values, MultiFernet stores the values and creates the cryptographic instance, but loses the ability to encrypt/decrypt.

My code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet,MultiFernet

keystore = []
message = b"foo bar"    

for x in range(4):
    keystore.append(Fernet.generate_key())

f = MultiFernet(keystore) # storing the list keystore creates a cryptographic instance here at f

token = f.encrypt(message) # Get error here, shown below
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 151, in encrypt return self._fernets[0].encrypt(msg)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encrypt'
```

Using the same key from the keystore in a single

```
d = Fernet(keystore[0])
```

will provide success, but attempting to follow the recipe as the documentation shows that this

```
g = MultiFernet([keystore[0],keystore[1]])
```

returns the same error as above (even extracting the keys to individual variables, where key1 = keystore[0], ect)

So I'm at a loss here.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research, I realized that the Fernet encryption must be applied after the key is generated for use in the MultiFernet token creation.

Example:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet,MultiFernet

keystore = []
keyfinal = []

message = b"foo bar"    
for x in range(4):

    keystore.append(Fernet.generate_key()) # generates the initial keys
    keyfinal.append(Fernet(keystore[x])) # Applies Fernet encryption to make usable keys

f = MultiFernet(keyfinal) # Set up MultiFernet on the keyfinal list
s = Fernet(keystore[2]) # Take a key from the initial keystore for single key encryption

token = s.encrypt(message) # encrypt using single key

print(f.decrypt(token)) # decrypt using MultiFernet
b"foo bar"
```